# client.destroy() not working on v12 discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Getting an error while trying to restart the client on discord.js
Found this code on this forum, it appears to work normal on the v12 client, but on mine its not working.

I did use before the command console.log to print out the code, and it prints out correct.
aswell i generated new token, still not working

the thing what i want is to let it fully restart by an command.
on v11 my script worked but this v12 not working anymore.

```
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

    if(message.author.id != "43437XXXX068625418") return message.channel.send("You're not bot the owner! https://i.imgur.com/8ep8YbI.gif")

    try {
        message.channel.send("53686XXXX7159040> Attempting a restart...").then(msg => {
          //msg.react('');
          setTimeout(function(){
             msg.edit("53686XXXX7159040> I should be back up now!");
          }, 10000);
        })
        console.log (config.Settings[0].bot_secret_token);
        client.destroy().then(client.login(config.Settings[0].bot_secret_token))
        



          } catch(e) {
            message.channel.send(`ERROR: ${e.message}`)

    }
  }
```

getting this error,

```
(node:9432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordjsError: Request to use to
en, but token was unavailable to the client.
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\discordbot2\new\node_modules\discord.js\src\r
st\RequestHandler.js:93:15)
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\discordbot2\new\node_modules\discord.js\src\r
st\RequestHandler.js:97:19)
    at RequestHandler.push (D:\discordbot2\new\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest
RequestHandler.js:39:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:9432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To termin
te the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandl
d-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejecti
ns_mode). (rejection id: 17)
(node:9432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordjsError: Request to use to
en, but token was unavailable to the client.
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\discordbot2\new\node_modules\discord.js\src\r
st\RequestHandler.js:93:15)
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\discordbot2\new\node_modules\discord.js\src\r
st\RequestHandler.js:97:19)
    at RequestHandler.push (D:\discordbot2\new\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest
RequestHandler.js:39:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:9432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To termin
te the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandl
d-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejecti
ns_mode). (rejection id: 18)
```

Comment: Where the `message` comes from?

Comment: [Client#destroy()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=destroy) Simply logs out the bot and ends connection to the Discord API

Comment: i know, but it doesnt work... nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.destroy()` doesn't return a promise, so you can simply log in again on the next line:

```js
client.destroy()
client.login(config.Settings[0].bot_secret_token)
```

Comment: When i do that what u said, nothing happens. regards

Comment: I get an confirmation text in discord, but client not restarting or doesnt do anything. still stays.@Zsolt Meszaros

Comment: well i can tell it still doesnt work. nothing happens. the client doesnt disconnect and reconnect at all